# Problem with MySQL compare between current month customers exists in previous month

Tags: mysql

In Summary, I have this transaction table (table_1).

It has customers making transaction from channels with date.

| _date | customer_id | total | channel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-13 | c1 | 10.0 | chan_A |
| 2021-01-13 | c2 | 20.0 | chan_A |
| 2021-01-14 | c3 | 10.0 | chan_B |
| 2021-01-15 | c4 | 14.0 | chan_C |
| 2021-01-17 | c5 | 15.0 | chan_D |
| 2021-02-13 | c1 | 10.0 | chan_A |
| 2021-02-13 | c2 | 20.0 | chan_A |
| 2021-02-13 | c2 | 20.0 | chan_B |
| 2021-02-13 | c6 | 20.0 | chan_B |

What I would like to get is,

For the month February 2021, I want to see

| _Year | _Month | channel | loyal | comeback |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2 | chan_A | 2 | 0 |
| 2021 | 2 | chan_B | 1 | 1 |

Loyal means customer exists in January 2021(prior) and February 2021 (current) two consecutive months.

comeback means customers those do not exists in January but exists in February.
(Side note: all those customers have made transaction some point in time before.)

What I have so far is -

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(_date) as _year, MONTH(_date) as _month, channel as _chan, customer_id
FROM table_1
WHERE YEAR(_date) = 2021 and MONTH(_date) = 2
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
FROM table_1
WHERE YEAR(_date) = 2021 and MONTH(_date) = 1
```

This is the part I do not know how to proceed.

For "customer_id" from each row in "Query 1", I want to check if it exists in "Query 2".

If exists, add 1 to loyal.
Else , add 1 to comeback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cte2` stands for your first query (query that get customers that are on month 2), and `cte1` is the query2.

I used left join to check if data exists in both query result or not.

```
with cte2 as (
  SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(_date) as _year, MONTH(_date) as _month, channel as _chan, customer_id
  FROM table_1
  WHERE YEAR(_date) = 2021 and MONTH(_date) = 2
),
cte1 as (
  SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
  FROM table_1
  WHERE YEAR(_date) = 2021 and MONTH(_date) = 1
),
cte3 as (
  select c2._year, c2._month, c2._chan, c2.customer_id as customer_id_jan, c1.customer_id as customer_id_feb
  from cte2 c2
  left join cte1 c1 on c1.customer_id = c2.customer_id
)
select _year, _month, _chan, count(customer_id_feb) as loyal, sum(case when customer_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as comeback
from cte3 c3
left join cte1 c1 on c3.customer_id_jan = c1.customer_id
group by _year, _month, _chan
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/g59hkbBv)